# VHDL - Object "x" is used but not declared

Tags: vhdl

Im new to VHDL and I'm doing some university exercises. It was all great until today when I got an error that I don't understand the reason of why it appears. Hope you could help me. (Software: Quartus Prime)

Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity AddSub4 is
 port(a, b : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        sub  : in std_logic;
        s    : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cout : out std_logic);
end AddSub4;

architecture Structural of AddSub4 is

  signal s_b : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin
    
sub_mux: s_b <= b when (sub='0') else
            not b;

final: entity work.Adder4(Structural)
         port map(cin  => sub,
                     a    => a,
                     b    => b,
                     cout => cout,
                     s    => s);
end Structural;

architecture Behave of AddSub4 is

    signal val1, val2, valFinal : unsigned(4 downto 0);
    
begin

    val1     <= '0' & unsigned(a);
    val2     <= '0' & unsigned(b);
    valFinal <= (val1 + val2) when (sub = '0') else (val1 - val2);
    s        <= std_logic_vector(valFinal(3 downto 0));
    cout     <= std_logic(valFinal(4));

end Behave;
```

The error in the terminal:

```
Error (10482): VHDL error at AddSub4.vhd(30): object "unsigned" is used but not declared
```

Comment: The type `unsigned` is declared in package `ieee.numeric_std`. You need to add `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`.

Comment: I did it but now shows other error:  
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at AddSub4.vhd(5) near text "entity";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."  Does it need that signs close to entity?

Comment: did you forget the semi-colon `;` ?

Comment: Where do you think I forgot to put a semi-colon? I could be wrong but I never wrote any type of sign close to entity!? So does it need a sign?

Comment: You have not updated your code with the numeric_std package,  so we can only guess what the new problem is.

Comment: True. *facePalm  I forgot to put the semi-colon after  `ieee.numeric_std.all` . Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a library you can either

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all ; 
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```